# ImageView scale type to crop image in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have an image and I want to put it to full the screen fitting by width but cropping the top of the image, like this:

[image]

The red area is the image and the red one is the phone screen/parent layout. Of course, preserving aspect ratio. Is it possible in XML instead of programatically?

Comment: orange is the real image and blue one is the image you want from it right?

Comment: please see my answer and let me know if any problem to implement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem using a custom view:

```
public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {

    public ResizableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable != null) {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int diw = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            if (diw > 0) {
                int height = width * drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / diw;
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
                return;
            }
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    }

}
```

And, the XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity" >

    <com.xxx.widgets.ResizableImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSplash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_splash"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok for that You should Do This Steps:--

```
1).  Make Linear Layout
2).  apply the image as background
3).  set the view at top to crop the background of layout.
```

i think you got what i am talking.

**for example this is the xml:--**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">//background color of your screen
    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="put the resource id of the image you want to crop"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
         <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="250dp"
          android:background="@android:color/white" // background color of your screen
          />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell me if there is any issue implementing it..

thanks enjoy,...

Comment: Okay! let me try and I will let you know :)

Comment: Oops!! not working, I think I didn't explain the problem well. I do want to crop the image, but it appears the full image resized.

Comment: no bro.. i think you did mistake in implementing it..:( its croping the image not resizing the image..

Comment: read the answer carefully and just do as i said in xml and you will find it solved

Comment: Blue rectangle corresponds to the phone screen while the orange one is the image, so the cropped part of the image should not be displayed since it must be above of the top screen margins.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40869/discussion-between-kailash-dabhi-and-didac-perez)

Comment: Finally I solved my problem! check out my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
android:src="@drawable/img"
android:scaleType="fitEnd"
```

instead of

```
android:background
```

fitEnd retains aspect ratio as is written [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#END)

Comment: It didn' work. Please check out my solution :) thank you so much